# python: итерационная замена подстрок в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, replace

Подскажите как правильно выполнить итерационную замену подстрок в строке

Например из строки `abcccccccccabcccccacccc` заменой `сс` на `c` должно получиться `abcabcac`

Конечно можно сделать таким способом:

```
text = 'abcccccccccabcccccacccc'
while True:
    tmp = text.replace('cc', 'c')
    if tmp == text:
        text = tmp
        break
    text = tmp
```

но это все таки в лоб (поэтому длинно, медленно и грубо), есть ли более правильные и элегантные способы?

через регулярки тоже эффект не окончательный (может есть флаг, указывающий на итерационную замену?):

```
text = 'abcccccccccabcccccacccc'
text = re.sub(r'cc', 'c', text, flags=итерационный)
```

Comment: а почему не c+ на c ? без циклов

Comment: Для замены нет таких флагов. Ваш подход в принципе подходит. Есть ещё вариант с `re.subn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так:

```py
from itertools import groupby

text = 'abcccccccccabcccccacccc'
res = ''.join([x[0] for x in groupby(text)])
```

res:

```
'abcabcac'
```

Еще вариант:

```
text = 'abcccccccccabcccccacccc'

res = ([text[x] for x in range(len(text)-1) if text[x]!=text[x+1]])
res.append(text[-1])
print("".join(res))
```

```
'abcabcac'
```

Comment: ну это как-то уже очень брутально - забили микроскопом гвозди :)

Comment: @Zhihar, скорее наборот, регулярки - это микроскоп (объект со сложным внутренним устройством). А тут (особенно в первом варианте) - все довольно явно и понятно.

Comment: вопрос скорее в производительности и используемым ресурсам

Comment: @Zhihar Регулярки в данном случае работают в ~3 раза медленнее чем мой второй вариант и в ~4 раза медленнее, чем первый.

Answer (score 2):

А какая проблема сделать это регуляркой?
Если нужно убрать дубли буквы `c`:

```
import re
text = 'aaaabcccccccccabbbbcccccacccc'
text = re.sub(r'c+', 'c', text)
# aaaabcabbbbcac
```

Если нужно убрать дубли любых символов:

```
text = re.sub(r'(.)(\1)+', r'\1', text)
# abcabcac
```

---

Если в результате замены может образоваться строка, в которой тоже требуется замена, то придётся процесс замены повторить.

```
import re
text = 'xxxxxa'
n = True
while n: (text, n) = re.subn(r'xa', 'a', text)
# text = 'a'
```

Comment: наверное лучше (\1)+, чтоб одиночные символы на сами себя не заменлись

Comment: Да, можно через +. Конечный результат будет тот же.

Comment: хотелось бы универсальное решение для любых подстрок
например убираем `xa` и меняем его на `a`, тогда `xxa` в конечном итоге должно стать `a`, а в регулярке тоже будет `xa`, потому что не итерационно выполнено, как я понимаю

Comment: @Zhihar [xa]+ => a

Comment: @GrAnd `x+a` => `a`

Comment: @splash58 Ага, щяз. А в строке `aaabcc` как без рекурсии заменить `abс` -> `b`? (на выходе должно получиться `ab`)

Comment: значит, x+a => xa

Comment: но, вообще-то, пока вопроса нет

Comment: @splash58 `x+a => a` и `x+a => xa` - взаимоисключающие алгоритмы. Первый неправильно сработает во втором случае, а второй - в первом.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zZeKiE/1

Comment: @splash58 Повторюсь...  А в строке `aaabcc` как без рекурсии заменить `abс` -> `b`? (на выходе должно получиться `ab`)

Comment: например, a+b+c+ => b

Comment: @splash58 Не пойдёт. выдаст неправильный ответ. Да и вообще, нужен универсальный подход. Ибо я как бы знаю, что для каждой строки всегда можно придумать отдельную регулярку.